# Rescaling MNDWI to normalize

Tags: envi

[image]

This statistic report shows the scale after done the MNDWI index process by using software ENVI 5.1.

Normally expect result have to be -1 to +1 scale.

How to get which scale?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you give some more information about your data, for example, what did you use as the input for the creation of your MNDWI raster?

Comment: i used this formula (float(b3)-float(b5))/(float(b3)+float(b5))

Comment: Please, include that new information in the post (https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/345036/edit). Do you have negative values for any pixel in band 3 or band 5?